# Advanced regex for unordered characters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

This seems simple but I've been struggling for hours now. The pattern is simple, a telephone number that optionally starts with a +, has 10-15 digits, and optionally has spaces, dashes or parentheses. The numbers and characters should be in no particular order.

I've tried using non-matching groups and seen so many different ways of validating phone numbers, but to no avail.

The best I have so far is `^\+?([0-9]{10-15}[)( -]*)$`, but it only accepts the other characters if they're at the end of the pattern. This expression will be used in a Java context.

Comment: Try this `^\+?(?:[ ()-]*\d){10,15)[ ()-]*$`

Comment: I will happily mark this as the correct answer if you post it, it seems to have done the trick. I don't know why the downvoting as this is not answered in the apparent "duplicate" question.

Answer (score -1):

Regular Expression

```
\+?([\s-]?[0-9]){10,15}+
```

as a Java string

```
"\\+?([\\s-]?[0-9]){10,15}+"
```